# PWA With React version 17.x.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

In ReactJS version 16.x.x, it very easy to make a Progressive Web Application by just changing

```js
serviceWorker.unregister()

// to

serviceWorker.register()
```

But when I installed React v 17.0.1 which am using right away, I cant find a **serviceWorker** file there, but I found a **reportWebVitals** file which is used for measuring performance ones your app. Is there a way to make My React Application of v17.x.x a PWA ?

Meanwhile: I have copied the serviceWorker.js file back to my workspace and also registered the application, but failed with this error message
`Error during service worker registration:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('MyWebsiteURL') with script ('MyWebsiteURL/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

Comment: Surely https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/ is still applicable?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , My project doesn't come with a serviceWorker file, but a reportWebVitals file

Comment: Sounds like it's time to ask over on https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues, pointing out that you're looking at the officials docs on https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/ and it doesn't match what you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
npx create-react-app project-name --template cra-template-pwa
```

The argument `--template cra-template-pwa` needs to be added because since the release CRA 4, the tool doesn’t provide built-in service workers. And the mentioned argument creates an application with a service worker.

Comment: What if my project already exist and I didn't use the pwa CRA template on setup